# Anyone else having an issue with Atom after 23.04 upgrade?

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, 23.04, intel-atom

I have an 'Acepc' tiny pc with a quad-core atom and an SSD - it had that cut-down Windows system.  This one is unusual because it has a bay for a laptop disk of which I have many.

Grub comes up fine.  Boot hangs though.  22.10 was OK pre upgrade
Memory test works OK and tells me I have Intel(R) Atom(TM) x5-Z2835 CPU @ 1.44GHz
CPU: 4 Cores 4 Threads  SMP: 4T (PAR)
Using All Cores.

Last messages are:

atomisp: Error -2 while requesting firmware shisp_2401a0_v21.bin
IUNIT power-off timeout.
Failed to switch off ISP.

Trying 5.19 kernel from 'Advanced options' boots OK.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the exact same error with an Asus T101HA.

With kernel 6.2.12 initially had same behavior. Now with added firmware file everything seems fine.

I took the firmware from the following link.

https://sbexr.rabexc.org/latest/sources/44/4f549ed412d6b8.html

Copied it into /lib/firmware.

Now it boots and, as a bonus, I have some video devices. Webcam works

Comment: Thank You. You were the first to find solution. Great that webcam works! However, since this bug makes it impossible to install 23.04 from live usb or to update with Ubuntu Update installer - atomisp modules will be disabled in Ubuntu kernel. The work is being done right now as I write this. Atomisp is not ready yet. So - next time you update the kernel - it may be that webcam won't work anymore. More info [here](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/issues/1095). @jwrdegoede is the person developing atomisp for linux.

Comment: This bug has been fixed in (K)Ubuntu 23.10 (Starting from Kernel 6.5.0-5.5). The web-camera works also!

Answer (score 0):

This bug is now fixed.

One can now install (K)Ubuntu 23.10 to an Intel Atom CPU computer.

The Web-camera works also.

However, one can still not make a fresh install of (K)Ubuntu 23.04.