# Not able to install (K)Ubuntu 23.04 in Intel Atom Computer

Tags: system-installation, kernel, 23.04, intel-atom

I did not success in installing Kubuntu 23.04 from live USB to HP x2 210 G2  which has  4 Intel Atom CPUs .

After selecting "Try or install Kubuntu" the install is stuck.

The last four lines in live session boot before stop:

```
[34.824672] atomisp-isp2 atomisp: Error - 2 while requesting firmware shisp_2401a0_v21.bin
[34.881487] atomisp-isp2 0000:00:03.0: IUNIT power-off timeout.
[43.884325] atomisp-isp2 0000:00:03:0: Failed to switch off ISP
[56.173277] watchdog: BUG: Soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 23s [systemd-udevd:1227]
```

Blacklisting [atomisp modules](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/57303#comment166144) in Live session grub did not solve the issue.

The same goes for updating 22.10 with Ubuntu Update-installer.

Comment: This is as you've said, likely a known bug, and as such it makes sense for you to continue the debugging and conversation on the bug reports, not here. There are some comments suggesting it's possible to get working. https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/issues/1095#issuecomment-1472426585

Comment: Have you tried blacklisting the module by editing grub or something similar? Add `atomisp.blacklist=1` on the part that normally has `quietsplash` or where you would normally add NOMODESET. So [probably select expert mode instead of NOMODESET](https://askubuntu.com/a/1182214/167115) and then add `atomisp.blacklist=1` A list of the [other related modules can be found here](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/57303#comment166144). And of course, you'd just add the `module_name.blacklist=1` for any you want to blacklist (replacing `module_name` with the actual name of the module, of course).

Comment: @mchid I have not tried editing grub yet. Normally it's beyond my skills, but with your kind advice I will try it. Thank you. This is just the kind of advice I was looking for. I have to study your advices a little bit more to see if I understood everything correctly. I may have ask your help later to clarify some of these concepts.

Comment: @popey Thank you for your comment. I'm familiar with this page - in fact, the last comment with name Lumipyry is mine. In Manjaro kernel 6.2 - or their Surface sub-kernel the system maintainer has disabled atomisp and related modules from the kernel, and this solves the problem as a workaround.

Comment: @SamiSaarinen, Good luck editing grub, and please share your result with us.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anyone else having an issue with Atom after 23.04 upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464713/anyone-else-having-an-issue-with-atom-after-23-04-upgrade)

Answer (score 7):

---

### UPDATE October 28th 2023

(K)Ubuntu 23.10 can now be installed - it comes with Kernel 6.5.0-10.

The web-camera works also.

[(K)Ubuntu 23.04 can not be installed.]

---

**UPDATE** October 14th.

This bug has been fixed in kernel 6.5.0-5.5.

---

**UPDATE** May 1st.

Solution found.

A fix in Ubuntu kernel is under work.  Atomisp modules will be disabled in kernel.

I will try to inform here when the kernel is updated - or you can follow the progress in [report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2017444).

You can still mark in the report if this issue affects you.

---

Intel Atom owners:

**Don't file reports of web-camera not working.**

It won't be working until atomisp is ready. Instead follow news  of atomisp development.

---

Meanwhile, as a temporary solution, here is  how to boot with kernel 6.2 (thanks @mchid):

Before update from 22.10 [download](https://github.com/intel-aero/meta-intel-aero-base/blob/master/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto/shisp_2401a0_v21.bin) firmware *shisp_2401a0_v21.bin* , copy it to `/lib/firmware` and you will be able to boot.

The same goes if you have 23.04 or any other linux running with previous kernel.

Original solution in: [Anyone else having an issue with Atom after 23.04 upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464713/anyone-else-having-an-issue-with-atom-after-23-04-upgrade/1464734#1464734)

---

---

*Additional information*

> The Kernel 6.2 misses *shisp_2401a0_v21.bin* and possibly more atomisp related drivers - This / these drivers were already missing in kernel 5.19, but then they "only" caused kernel panic. ***Now this issue has escalated to a point where the OS does not boot at all***.

> The newest Ubuntu Kernel 6.3.0 still has this issue.

> This issue is not limited to Ubuntu and Kubuntu - but concerns all Linux distributions in computers with Intel Atom CPU with kernel 6.2 or higher:

> This issue has been [reported](https://www.mail-archive.com/kernel-packages@lists.launchpad.net/msg501664.html) in Ubuntu bugtracking system for Ubuntu 23.04 Beta.
>  It has also been reported by [Arch Linux](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=283920)
>   and [Manjaro Linux](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/issues/1095) users.

> What then is this "*atomisp*" which causes all this trouble?
> - It is a Web-camera module intended for Intel Atom CPU computers.

Comment: So according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1464734/167115) you can boot using an older kernel and then download and copy the file into `/lib/firmware` and then you should be able to boot kernel 6.2. If the installer USB uses kernel 6.2, then install an older version of Ubuntu like 22.10 or 22.04 and then [use the system to upgrade to a newer version](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/upgrading-ubuntu-desktop#:~:text=You%20can%20find%20the%20Software,have%20not%20yet%20been%20enabled.)

Comment: So make sure the `shisp_2401a0_v21.bin` file is in `/lib/firmware` before you upgrade. Or at the very least, make sure the `shisp_2401a0_v21.bin` file is in `/lib/firmware`  before you reboot after the system upgrade.

Comment: Of course, if you are already running 22.04 or 22.10, then (hopefully) all you have to do is copy the file in place and then follow the upgrade instructions.

Comment: I do have running Kubuntu 23.04 with kernel 6.1.25 - by (sudo do-release-upgrade). But I'm also thinking about future here. (K)Ubuntu 22.10 will only be available for 90 days now. A fresh install of 23.04 is impossible now. I also hope my bug report gets attention enought that this is fixed in kernel. Now a basic linux user is doing patches that are job of kernel.org. And after year or two - in order to have the latest (K)Ubuntu, one has to do several distribution upgrades from 22.04 or 22.10 to achieve it.

Comment: By a quick look it seems that in ( https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464713/anyone-else-having-an-issue-with-atom-after-23-04-upgrade/1464734#1464734 ) they found solution and Your answer solves it too. I think You have solved this. Thank You again, I appreciate this! I will modify my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

#### The following instructions will blacklist the atomisp modules.

When you boot the USB live session:

##### If you see a GRUB screen

- press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit
- navigate to the line that says `quiet splash`
- add `atomisp.blacklist=1` on the same line, before `quiet splash`
- press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot

##### If you do not see a GRUB screen

(I haven't tested this but I'm pretty sure these instructions are mostly correct. Unlike [these similar instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/1182214/167115), we just need to add a custom entry using "expert mode" instead of `nomodeset`)

- press <kbd>F6</kbd> and then select **expert mode**
- manually enter `atomisp.blacklist=1`
- then press <kbd>ESC</kbd> (?)
- select "try ubuntu without installing"
- if it works fine, then proceed with the installation from there

---

#### After installation:

If you cannot boot up after installation, then follow the ***if you see a GRUB screen*** instructions above.

- after you boot up, run the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

- navigate to the line that says `quiet splash`
- add `atomisp.blacklist=1` before `quiet splash`
- press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save your changes
- press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano
- run the following command to apply the changes

```
sudo update-grub
```

Please post any future errors.

Comment: I blacklisted **all** the drivers mentioned here " [link] (https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/57303#comment166144) " and changed quiet splash to profile (to see boot process). Nope. " atomips error -2 while requesting firmware shisp_2401a0_v21.bin ".

Comment: mchid - Thank you for your answer. You spent Your valuable time and effort and created a model example of a perfect answer. It is most clear and precise - one can not make mistakes by following Your instructions. Yours most humbly, Sami Saarinen